# How to consume Jenkins API Rest in Google Kubernetes Engine from external clients

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-shell

I want to try out continuous deployment with Jenkins on Google Kubernetes Engine. Of course, by using the Jenkins API Rest.

I have gone through https://cloud.google.com/solutions/jenkins-on-container-engine-tutorial

I got Jenkins running. The problem is with regard to the Jenkins API Rest **when I try to consume it by using Postman or curl**. I'm prompted to Sign in to continue to Google Cloud Shell.

**By using curl**

curl -X GET https://8080-dot-3828316-dot-devshell.appspot.com/job/dev.ci/api/json\?pretty\=true --user USER:TOKEN

```
<a href="https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=618104708054-jqgabbtcm3fusmhf5hu82r7j8emh7aoa.apps.googleusercontent.com&amp;redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fdevshell.appspot.com%2F_cloudshellProxy%2Foauth2callback&amp;response_type=code&amp;scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email&amp;state=eyJYU1JGVG9rZW4iOiJYUEljQkFETS1uVVFaMndLaF9uMjFvRUhENW86MTU4OTY3NDUzMDE3OSIsIkFwcFVSTCI6Imh0dHBzOi8vODA4MC1kb3QtMzgyODMxNi1kb3QtZGV2c2hlbGwuYXBwc3BvdC5jb20vam9iL2Rldi5jaS9hcGkvanNvbj9wcmV0dHk9dHJ1ZSJ9">Found</a>.
```

**In Postman**

[image]

**In incognito window**

[image]

Comment: Did you generated this OAuth key through `APIs & Services > Credentials` or are you using your account key to access Jenkins API? Where did you get this Key from?

Comment: Yes I have my credentials but according to the this documentation https://cloud.google.com/solutions/jenkins-on-kubernetes-engine-tutorial, they only make a fast forward 8080:8080 to the container I think. All the clusters are ClusterIP type. Maybe that's why I can't connect to my url directly without making a OAuth2. So I don't know how to send my google credentials and my jenkins credentials all together in one request. Or I will have to look for another tutorial...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was related to the fact that I didn't expose the service properly. I was using the preview URL that Google provides you. So I had to follow the architecture shown here: https://cloud.google.com/solutions/jenkins-on-kubernetes-engine?fbclid=IwAR19Dl_kUSGzK1cfqyYA1s9cNt26CBnSgXf6zV104NGtIiXNtpTTKrfo3TI. I had to expose my jenkins ui as a NodePort and learn about ingress.